# Dojo simple lightbox

Tags: dojo

I've searched the web for a simple lightbox using dojo, and I've had no luck whatsoever!
Most of the examples use the dojo Dialog which IMHO is quite fugly.
I would like the ability just to display an arbitrary div with dimmed background, and I'll be in charge complete of what content is shown.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in dojox.image?   There are both [Lightbox and LightboxDialog](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/image/Lightbox.html) variations.  The [plain lightbox](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.5.0/dojo-release-1.5.0/dojox/image/tests/test_Lightbox.html) doesn't have much styling.  The Dialog one probably offers a choice of Dijit themes.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the svn trunk > /dojox/image/tests. There are plenty of examples.

http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/dojox/trunk/image/tests/

Tip : Prevent multiple instances of Lightbox ! Use a singleton instead !